# Stdin to second command / password protected zip with php

Tags: php, bash, zip, stdin

I'm hoping to create a oneliner that converts the stdin stream to a (named) file in a password protected zip archive.

So far I've got:

```
mkfifo importlog.txt; cat - > importlog.txt & zip --password testpass - --fifo importlog.txt; rm importlog.txt;
```

This works fine when I replace `cat -` with `echo "content"`, but with the `cat -` in place a zip file is created with an empty importlog.txt. My preference really is to stream the content, as it will be quite a lot.

I think my question is how to stream stdin to the second command, but it's very much possible I've overlooked an other solution. I'm trying to use this from a php script with `proc_open` and fwrite.

Comment: Can you add what actually happens now, i.e. what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I've added it: it creates the zipfile with an empty importlog.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to solve this as a single line of bash code. I ended up writing a larger php function that streams the content through a named pipe.

```
function createSingleFileZipArchive($filename, $contents, $password = null){

    $filename = (string) $filename;
    if(mb_strlen(trim($filename)) === 0){
        throw new LengthException('Filename empty');
    }

    //create subfolder in tempdir containing process id to prevent concurrency issues
    $tempDir = sys_get_temp_dir().'/phpzip-'.getmypid();
    if(!is_dir($tempDir)){
        mkdir($tempDir);
    }

    //create FIFO and start zip process that reads fifo stream
    $madeFifo = posix_mkfifo($tempDir.'/'.$filename, 0600);
    if($madeFifo === false){
        throw new RuntimeException('failed to create fifo to stream data to zip process.');
    }
    $proc = proc_open('cd '.$tempDir.'; zip'.($password === null ? null : ' --password '.escapeshellarg($password)).' - --fifo '.escapeshellarg($filename), [['pipe', 'r'],['pipe', 'w'],['pipe', 'w']], $pipes);
    if($proc === false){
        throw new RuntimeException('failed to start zip-process');
    }

    //write to fifo
    $in = fopen($tempDir.'/'.$filename, 'w'); //always open fifo writer after reader is opened, otherwise process will lock
    fwrite($in, $contents);
    fclose($in);

    //get output before reading errors.
    //If no errors/debug output was generated the process could otherwise hang.
    $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);

    //check if any errors occurred
    if ($err = stream_get_contents($pipes[2])) {
        $errorOutput = [];
        foreach(explode($err,PHP_EOL) as $errLine){
            $errLine = trim($errLine);
            if(strlen($errLine) > 0 && strpos($errLine, 'Reading FIFO') === false && strpos($errLine, 'adding:') === false){ //ignore default notices.
                $errorOutput[] = trim($errLine);
            }
        }
        if(count($errorOutput) > 0){
            throw new RuntimeException("zip-error: ".implode('; ',$errorOutput));   
        }
    }

    //cleanup
    foreach($pipes as $pipe){
        fclose($pipe);
    }
    proc_close($proc);
    unlink($tempDir.'/'.$filename);
    rmdir($tempDir);

    //done
    return $output;

}

file_put_contents('importlog.zip',createSingleFileZipArchive('importlog.txt','test contents','testpass'));
```